# how can i solve this with copy and rename function in php

Tags: php, copy, rename

trying to write a pgm for downloading the weblinks and storing it into the file. for this i have used rename and copy function like this

```
rename("C:/Users/Default/Desktop/filename.xml", "C:/Users/Default/Desktop/$_POST[name]$id.xml");

copy("D:/installFiles/wamp/www/WebApplication1/web/WEB-INF/filename.html", "$_POST[name]   
$id.html") or die("could not copy".mysql_error());
```

after executing ths iam getting following warnings. here no contents are copying into file from the weblinks or webpages which i have downloaded.

```
 Warning: rename(C:/Users/Default/Desktop/filename.xml,C:/Users/Defaul/Desktop/ayrveda    

  yoga27.xml) [function.rename]: No error in  
  D:\Installations\wamp\www\webpagedownloader\sqldb.php on line 58

  Warning: copy(D:/installFiles/wamp/www/WebApplication1/web/WEB-INF/filename.html)
  [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
  D:\Installations\wamp\www\webpagedownloader\sqldb.php on line 63

  could not copy
```

line 58 has rename function and line 63 has copy function.
1) how to remove this warnings and also i should be able to copy from webpages to file?
2) can we run php programs which are edited in netbeans through apache tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@rename("C:/Users/Default/Desktop/filename.xml", "C:/Users/Default/Desktop/".$_POST[name].$id.".xml");

//and
@copy("D:/installFiles/wamp/www/WebApplication1/web/WEB-INF/filename.html", $_POST[name].   
$id.".html") or die("could not copy");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hmmm:-( there is no warnings displaying. but contents of file couldn't  copy.